# Suggestions on simulating fuse characteristics electronically?

Tags: power-supply, fuses

Assume that we have an isolation transformer 230V in 230V out and that we measure the output current with a current transformer with known transfer function. We compare the current to a settable value and if over, then we trip a relay that disconnects the output. This kind of fuse will be almost infinitely fast, something that is not always desireable. So, what about this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flbSRI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U1 is a true RMS ic such as the AD 8436. The values of the RC link should be something else, the comparator a real comparator etc. I just drew to illustrate the idea, being that I could vary the characteristics of the "fuse" by changing the RC time constant. Now the time taken to reach the trip point will depend on how much larger the measured current is or t = -LN(1-(1/n)), where n is by how much we have overcurrent.

If we assume that the time constant is 10s, then the fuse will trip after 7s if the current is 2x over, 2.8s if 4x and 1s if 10x. One could also change the time constant to be something else on discharge by adding a diode and resistor over R1

Would this be a workable idea for an electronic fuse?

Comment: sounds generally fine, but you'd want to make sure that brownouts etc don't lead to the relay being unexpectedly closed. Other than that, if you have a comparator at hand and a reliable supply to drive it: U1->comparator->RC->comparator so that you get a well-defined voltage at the input of the filter

Comment: Just as a remark: a relay is not infinitely fast. In fact it is very slow, much slower then a standard fuse. (That was the reason why the head of the machine lab at my school would use only real fuses and made us pay 16 cents for each fuse we blew).

Comment: Good point! I guess I could use an SSR instead. Yes. I have similar memories of expensive fuses. The purpose of the latch is to make sure that it remains tripped until reset.

Comment: A fuse is chosen to heat up with a thermal runaway due to conductor PTC resistance characteristics faster than the target being protected. For this reason, a linear time filter does not emulate this response. THe result is low loss below thermal runaway and high resistance and detonating to air gap when exceeded. So the time current response curves are not more logarithmic but not precisely with Amp-second response times.  Grid protection algorithms are much more complex,  But CT's can be saturated easily from OC which results in an impedance drop to zero increasing fault current rapidly.

Comment: But this circuit is not linear. Rather logarithmic. The CT is chosen in such a way that the current handling capability is well beyond the rated capacity of the transformer. I realise that it will not emulate a fuse perfectly though.